# I used appodeal and my app show error "admob not found" please

Tags: android

I have recently change my PC & installed fresh eclipse.

Now I run my application in new pc it's not Showing add and tost a error msg "admob not found"

Whats the problem..?

Comment: Install Android Studio and run your application on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its done this is because of my Google ply services.jar
In previous its works fine with adding folder google-play-services_libs.
but why i don't know in new pc i have to added Google ply services.jar to in libraries Direct. and its done it. i have seen some on web that new build tool is not add Google ply services.jar from private libraries file in apk. anyway its fine now

Comment: I also had an issue with libraries ones, not GP's, but still. Just sent the apk to their support specialist for checking and he fixed everything in an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using account that was created on your old pc and that it was linked up with appodeal via their plugin for chrome. Or try to synchronize them again making all steps from the beginning. btf they have cool support responding quickly